# Values vanishing after leaving function

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value

I'm writing a function to insert into a tree and the data can be seen (printed) after insertion within the function but when trying to see it in main nothing happens.

```c
node *tree = NULL;
insert(tree, 4321);
printf("outer: %d\n", tree->data);

void insert(node* tree, int data) {
  if (tree == NULL) {
    tree = new_node(data);
    printf("inner: %d\n", tree->data);
  }
}
```

This gives:

```
inner: 4321
```

It should be:

```
inner: 4321
outer: 4321
```

Comment: Classic problem of [pass by value vs pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: I your code tree is a pointer to a variable. When you call tree = xxx you set the pointer to a new memory location and the original tree pointer is unaltered, pointing to the old empty tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, `tree` is passed as an argument to the function, and by-status which is a pass-by-value in C. Any change made to `tree` itself inside the function will not be reflected back to the caller.

You need to pass a pointer to `tree`, if you want to modify `tree` from the called function.

Something like

```
void insert(node** tree, int data) {
  if (*tree == NULL) {
    *tree = new_node(data);
    printf("inner: %d\n", (*tree)->data);
  }
}
```

and call it like

```
insert(&tree, 4321);
```

Comment: ```node *tree = NULL;``` means it's a pointer does it not?

Comment: @FraserLangton Yes, but check carefully, what are you trying to change from the called function, the content of the memory pointed to by the pointer, or the pointer itself? Pointer or not, all function arguments are passed by value in C.

Comment: @Fraser Langton, Re "*`node *tree = NULL;` means it's a pointer does it not?*", Yes, but it's not a pointer to that which you want to modify. You want to modify the caller's `tree`, so you need to pass a pointer to the caller's `tree`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize tree as a pointer

```
node *tree = NULL;
```

This means, that the content of the variable is a memory location where your tree is stored.

When you pass that memory location to a function, it's value gets copied to the local variable inside the function.

When you call

```
tree = new_node(data);
```

what you're doing is assigning a new memory location to the local variable of the `tree` pointer inside your function. The pointer outside your function still has the same value and points to a memory location with no nodes.

What you'll need to do in order to edit the node inside your function is either define some kind of setter for your node, or set the data property explicitly with `tree->data = xxx`. This will alter the content of the memory `tree` is pointing to rather than altering its memory location.